# How to split a dataframe line into a multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5  6
0   A   B   C   D   E   F  G
1   H   I   J   K   L   M  N
2   O   P   Q   R   S   T  U
3   V   W   X   Y   Z
```

I want to split every line into multiples line in the random condition(it can be any condition):

For example,

```
df['2'],df['4],df['6]
df['0'],df['3']
df['1'],df['5']
```

In this case, these three rows should be repeated for every row in the input data frame.

Expected output:

```
C   E   G
A   D
B   F
J   L   N
H   K
I   M
Q   S   U
O   R
P   T
X   Z
V   Y
W
   #should repeat for other rows too
```

Headers are not required or I can ignore them while converting to csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify columns names in list, then in list comprehension filter it and convert columns to default `range` columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html), join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), replace missing values and create default index:

```
vals = [['2','4','6'], ['0','3'], ['1','5']]

L = [df.loc[:, x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for x in vals]
df = pd.concat(L).sort_index(kind='mergesort').fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    0  1  2
0   C  E  G
1   A  D   
2   B  F   
3   J  L  N
4   H  K   
5   I  M   
6   Q  S  U
7   O  R   
8   P  T   
9   X  Z   
10  V  Y   
11  W
```

Comment: instead of vals, if there are names of headers then

Comment: @AtomStore - Can you explian more?

Comment: in the headers instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 if there are header names and I want to arrange it by header names, Can I use df.loc instead of df.iloc in the line 2?