# How to fill nan column with natural numbers beginning in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data-frame

```
      Columns
0     Nan
1     Nan
2     Nan
3     Nan
```

I want to fill all the Nan columns here with natural numbers starting from 1 to rest of the empty columns in increasing order.

Expected Output

```
       Columns
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
```

Any suggestions to do this?

```
df['Columns'] = df['Columns'].fillna(??????????)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution if need replace only missing values use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then `True`s are processing like `1`:

```
m = df['Columns'].isna()
#nice solution from @Ch3steR, thank you
df.loc[m, 'Columns'] = m.cumsum()
#alternative
#df.loc[m, 'Columns'] = range(1, m.sum() + 1)
print (df)
   Columns
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
```

Test for another data:

```
print (df)
   Columns
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    100.0
3      NaN

m = df['Columns'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'Columns'] = m.cumsum()
print (df)
   Columns
0      1.0
1      2.0
2    100.0
3      3.0
```

If need set values by range, so original column values are overwritten, use:

```
df['Columns'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
print (df)
   Columns
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
```

Comment: It will be great if you could help me out on this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545072/how-to-split-a-dataframe-line-into-a-multiple-dataframes